# Prolog - parsing functions with DCG

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg

I need to parse a string representing function like this:

```
<fsignature>"(" <term1>, <term2> ... <termn>")"
```

The function' signature and terms also have to be controlled further for the function to be accepted.
I've written this DCG in Prolog:

```
fsign --> {is_leg(A)}, [A].
terms --> (funct, funct; terms).
terms --> (terms, terms; term).
term --> {is_term(T)}, [T].
```

But it doesn't seem to work, when I try to use phrase(funct, [foo, "(", a, a, ")"]). it goes into overflow. is_leg just checks if the string is legal (a string starting with a character), while is_term should check if the term is a literal (either a constant, a variable or a function).

What is that it's not working? I figure, probably the variables - should I put them as arguments of the nonterminals?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Something like, `terms --> (terms, terms ; term).` is the same as: `terms --> terms, terms.` and `terms --> term.` The first is clearly going to be an infiinite recursion. It's unclear what you want this rule to say.

Comment: The functions could have arity n, so it could possibly have an infinite number of arguments, that's why I put in that rule. The language should be infinite, but it should tell me which strings are accepted and what aren't, shouldn't it?

Comment: You don't mean it would have an infinite number of arguments, do you? You really mean it could have *any* number of arguments, but any given term has a finite number. There's just no limit to how many. At some point, the parsing has to finish, meaning the input sequence has a finite number of elements.

Comment: Yes, that's what I actually meant, poor choice of words!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your expressions all look like this:

```
<fsignature> "(" <term1> <term2> ... <termn> ")"
```

Then writing this out in terms of DCG, it should look something like this (minus any string validation predicates you're suggesting):

```
expression --> fsignature, ['('], terms, [')'].
fsignature --> ...      % whatever fsignature looks like
terms --> term.         % "terms" is a single term, or...
terms --> terms, term.  %   ... more terms followed by a single term.
term --> ...            % whatever a term looks like
```

You can also write the definition of `terms` as:

```
terms --> term | terms, term.
```

Note that the non-recursive definition of `terms` occurs before the recursive one. Also, the definition for `terms` above assumes that you must have at least one term (this requirement wasn't stated in your question).

Comment: That was it, I'm really grateful! That `terms --> terms, terms` rule was wrong, I was reasoning by doubling the number of terms in the function, not by increasing it with a single term every recursion - my reasoning was wrong anyway. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @Dodicin glad it was helpful! By the way, to make a code snippet in your comment, use back ticks. :)